# Node.js - place Json object elements into indivual divs in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have an array of JSON objects. For each object I want to use an individual div to hold and display each object.
I have seen multiple examples using html tables and rows but I need to specifically use divs for this task.
I tried now for a while but am none the wiser. So in this spirit I turn to you , the friends and comrades at Stackoverflow nation

```
   <div id="each">
        <div>
            id
        </div>
        <div>
            title
        </div>
        <div>
            price
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "foo1",
        price: 44
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "foo2",
        price:78
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "foo3",
        price:98
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "foo4",
        price: 20

    }
];
```

```
function builddiv(target, articles) {
    articles.forEach((e) => {
        target.innerHTML += `<div> ${e.id} </div><div> ${e.title} </div><div> ${e.price} </div>`;
    });
    }
builddiv(document.getElementById("each"), data);
```

Comment: You have to create them and append them individually. Example:

```js
function builddiv(target, articles) {
  articles.forEach((e) => {
    const divContainer = document.createElement('div');
    
    const idDiv = document.createElement('div');
    idDiv.textContent = `id: ${e.id}`;
    divContainer.appendChild(idDiv);
   
    
    target.appendChild(divContainer);
  });
}
```

Comment: @NoubarK. Thanks for the reply. It helped me, I had to change a few things and add some logic but at least you put me on the right path. 
Copy and paste you reply as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

By the way since the divs are ordered descending i.e verticaly do you perhaps have some css code to align each row horizontaly i.e each object next to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create them and append them individually. Example:

```js
function builddiv(target, articles) {
  articles.forEach((e) => {
    const divContainer = document.createElement('div');
    
    const idDiv = document.createElement('div');
    idDiv.textContent = `id: ${e.id}`;
    divContainer.appendChild(idDiv);
   
    
    target.appendChild(divContainer);
  });
}
```

Furthermore, if you want to store them horizontally, what you can do is add the following css properties to your main parent div.

```css
.parent-div-class{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

This should store you're cards horizontally instead of vertically.

Hope this helped!